# Path independence of an integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I'm studying for a test (that's why I've been asking so much today,) and one of the questions is about saying if an integral is path independent and then solving for it. 
I was reading online about path independence and it's all about vector fields, and I'm very, very lost.
This is the integral
$$\int_{0}^{i} \frac{dz}{1-z^2}$$
So should I find another equation that gives the same result with those boundaries? I honestly just don't know how to approach the problem, any links or topics to read on would be appreciated as well.
Thank you!

Comment: When you write $\,\int\limits_0^i\,$ , do you mean the vertical straight line along the imaginary axis between $\,0\,$ and $\,i\,$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio I believe the point of the exercise is that the integral (may) generally be a function of the path we pick between the given endpoints, so the path is not to be assumed fixed (unless we were to show it is path-independent).

Comment: so how do you think should I approach the question, trying to prove it's path independent, or disprove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do the following. Consider two paths joining $0$ and $i$: one will be a vertical segment, and another one going somehow around the point $z=1$ (for example, a counterclockwise sequence of three segments $0\rightarrow 1-i\rightarrow 2+i\rightarrow i$. The difference of integrals along these two paths will be given by an integral along a closed contour around $z=1$, which can be evaluated by Cauchy integral formula to be
$$ \oint_{z=1}\frac{dz}{1-z^2}=2\pi i \left[\frac{1}{z+1}\right]_{z=1}=\pi i.$$
So the integral is not path independent.

In general, if the integrand has at least one simple pole, the integral will depend on the chosen path.

Comment: wow this is great, so it isn't path independent because the difference of integrals wasn't 0?

Comment: Yes. The only thing that should be stressed: if you vary the integration contour "a bit", the value of the integral will not change. For it to change, the path should go in a different way with respect to singular points of the integrand.

Comment: thank you, this was indeed very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

*Seeing other answers, the follםwing perhaps doesn't grab the OP's intention, but here it is anyway.*

Putting $\,z=x+iy\implies\,z^2=x^2-y^2+2xyi\,$ , so along the $\,y$-axis from zero to $\,i\,$ we get:

$$x=0\;,\;\;0\le y\le 1\implies \frac1{1-z^2}=\frac1{1+y^2}\;,\;\;dx=0 \;,\;\;dz=i\,dy\;,\;\ \;\text{so}$$

$$\int\limits_0^i\frac{dz}{1-z^2}=\left.\int\limits_0^1\frac{i\,dy}{1+y^2}= i\arctan y\right|_0^1=\frac\pi 4i$$

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy analytic primitive of $\frac 1 2 \log (1+z) - \frac 1 2 \log (1-z)$ on $\mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R \cup (-1,1)$ if you pick the correct branch of the logarithm. So it's certainly path independent if the path doesn't pass through the wrong parts of $\mathbb R$, i.e. don't pass through $|r|\geq 1$

Comment: Any branch of the complex logarithm I know takes out the point zero, which is precisely the integral's  lower  limit. How can we fix that?

Comment: @DonAntonio A lower limit of $0$ would be a problem if the primitive was simply $\log z$, but this primitive is a bit different (in particular, this primitive is analytic in a nbhd of $0$).

Comment: That's a good point, @anon. Thanks.